# Posicionar el banner de publicidad correctamente

Tags: java, android-layout, android-fragment, admob

No se está mostrando bien el banner de publicidad en mi layout.

El include del content_main está ocupando toda la pantalla (excepto el espacio del toolbar superior que si lo respeta) sin dejar sitio para el banner.

Actualmente el banner se ve sobrepuesto al content_main. ¿Como sería el xml correcto para que quede sitio para todo?

app_bar_main.xml

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.rentabilidaddelalquiler.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#00FAFAFA"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|top"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/cardview_light_background"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/unlike" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/publicidad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/prueba">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Este es el contenido del include:

content_main.xml

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.rentabilidaddelalquiler.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo he solucionado de esta forma. Poniendo el atributo layout_above,creando un relative_layout y sacando el AdView del coordinator.

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.rentabilidaddelalquiler.MainActivity">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/publicidad">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#00FAFAFA"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|top"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/cardview_light_background"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/unlike" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/publicidad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/prueba">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
```